Text to Openpose and Weird RNN bugs
I want to create AI that generate openpose from textual description for example if input "a man running" output would be like the image I provided Is there any model architecture recommend for me?
my data condition is

canvas_width: 900px
canvas_height: 300px
frames: 5 (5 person)

expected output
I trying to train RNN for this task and I use sentence transformer for embedding text and then pass to RNN and the loss is look like image below
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer 
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
text = "a man running"
text_input = torch.tensor(sentence_model.encode(text), dtype=torch.float)

loss image with num_layers=3
My RNN setting
embedding_dim = 384
hidden_dim = 512
num_layers = 3
output_dim = 180
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.001
rnn_model = RNN(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, output_dim)

but the problem is whatever I input the output is the same everytime! but when I try changing num_layers to 1 and keep other setting the same like this
embedding_dim = 384
hidden_dim = 512
num_layers = 1
output_dim = 180
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.001
rnn_model = RNN(embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, output_dim)

the loss now look like this
loss image with num_layers=1
and now the problem is gone !!
Also I try to check the cause of the "output is the same everytime" problem I check dataloader and other code but no problem was found only num_layers=3 that cause the problem num_layers=1 fixed it
This is my training loop
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(rnn_model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

trainingEpoch_loss = []
validationEpoch_loss = []

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    step_loss = []
    rnn_model.train()
    for idx, train_inputs in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = rnn_model(torch.unsqueeze(train_inputs['text'], dim=0))
        training_loss = criterion(outputs, train_inputs['poses'])
        training_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        step_loss.append(training_loss.item())

        if (idx+1) % 1 == 0: print (f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Step [{idx+1}/{len(train_dataloader)}], Loss: {training_loss.item():.4f}')
    trainingEpoch_loss.append(np.array(step_loss).mean())

    rnn_model.eval()
    for idx, val_inputs in enumerate(val_dataloader):
      validationStep_loss = []
      outputs = rnn_model(torch.unsqueeze(val_inputs['text'], dim=0))
      val_loss = criterion(outputs, val_inputs['poses'])
      validationStep_loss.append(val_loss.item())
    validationEpoch_loss.append(np.array(validationStep_loss).mean())

This is my Inference
text = "a man running"
processed_text = torch.tensor(sentence_model.encode(text), dtype=torch.float)
output_poses = rnn_model(processed_text.unsqueeze(0))
print(output_poses.shape) #shape=(1, 180) 1 person is 36 (original data for 1 person is 54 but I change to 36 because I want only x and y and not z so cut out the z axis) and there's 5 person so 5*36 = 180

My question is

Is there any model architecture recommend for this task other than RNN?
Why whatever I input the output is the same everytime when num_layers=3 I'm very confused because the loss wouldn't go down if the model was giving the same output right? that's mean it give the same output in the Inference phase

Expected Answer

Model architecture that suit best for my task any papers or github repo related given would be appreciated
Answer why whatever I input the output is the same everytime when num_layers=3

